# Trying to paste something in node.js-prompt it changes my letters and even makes some of them disappear

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Here is an example: I copy/pasted `my name is john` into the terminal and it goes normally, but when I try to paste it in node prompt it gives me something like this: `my noaeo so ooh`.

[image: Example]

If I write it manually it goes smoothly. It only leads to problems when copy pasted.
I've updated my node from `v10.15.3` to `v12.22.6`. Also tried reinstalling vscode. None of this seem to work.

Comment: This is something to do with Powershell I think, can you try doing the same in command prompt?

Comment: It does the same exact thing in command prompt